# Difference between "estimation" and "evaluation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, comparisons

I know they have different meanings, as I can find both in some texts, where they are not considered as synonyms. I give an example, but my question is not limited to this example.

> We then contrast the predictions of this price image model with the
>   predictions of reference price models in four domains: price
>   evaluation, price estimation, choice, and inference making... <sub>[Source](http://home.uchicago.edu/ourminsky/Hamilton_Urminsky.pdf)</sub>

My question is:

What is the difference between "estimate/estimation" and "evaluating/evaluation".

What is the difference when I talk about prices?

Comment: An evaluation is made of what is known, for example today's share prices. An estimation is made for something that is not yet known, for example tomorrow's share prices.

Comment: Thank you. Could you turn it into an answer please?

Comment: The question has been flagged by some commenters as off-topic because of lack of research presented. For an answer to be sustainable, I'll have to do that research and present reliable sources to back it up.

Comment: You didn't include a link to your source (I've added it). It doesn't seem to be *explicitly* stated there, but they seem to distinguish ***price evaluation*** from ***price estimation*** on the grounds that the former refers to *how consumers differentiate between different sources and types of information about prices* (giving more "weight" to some than to others, for example). Whereas the latter is simply about how accurately people can "guess" the price of something if they don't actually "know" it.

Comment: It’s not English, it’s academic bullshit. Ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

As nouns the difference between estimation and evaluation is that estimation is the process of making an estimate while evaluation is an assessment, such as an annual personnel performance review used as the basis for a salary increase or bonus, or a summary of a particular situation.

source: [evaluation vs estimation](https://wikidiff.com/evaluation/estimation)

Comment: This would be improved if you stated more directly the difference between a "price evaluation" and a "price estimation".

Comment: There are certainly contexts in which there is a clear distinction between 'price evaluation' and 'price estimation'. Consider: 'how much do you think that house will sell for?' - price estimation - versus ' I would not buy it at that price' - price evaluation. But - a very big but - if what you wanted to communicate turned on that distinction then you should emphasise the point. The very fact that we are debating it on this site shows that the distinction is not obvious to all.

Comment: I saw this like you explained, Jeremy, but I'm not a native. Could etymology explain a difference?

Comment: Estimation looks at the more immediate factors. I think evaluation looks at a broader context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an illustrative example. Let's say that I were selling you an orange

1. Based on your past orange purchases, you would *estimate* the price of this orange
2. If I were to tell you the price of my orange, you would *evaluate* if my price is reasonable.

Comment: I understood that this ways (but I'm not a native), do you have some references?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a formal reference. Estimate is more common in engineering/operations related situations. Consider "I expect to be there by 7" vs "My estimated time of arrival is 7". Same context; the latter is more prevalent with engineers.